# Check field with at least one or more digits and including characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I'm making a contact form which will be submitted with jQuery and I'm stuck on one simple validation.

I need to validate a field, which has to have at least x integers.

How can I do this?

p.s: please don't suggest validation plugin.

Thanks,

edit: This is what I've tried, but it's wrong I guess.

```
var numbercheck = /^(\w\d{7,14})?$/;
```

this is jsdiffle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4WqY9/

Comment: When the submit button is clicked I'd check that the value in the field has at least *x* integers.

Comment: @Lazarus - Well that's what exactly I'm stuck at. I don't know how to 'check the value in the field has at least x integers'.

Comment: As you are stuck, what have you tried (post your code) and why don't you want to consider a validation plugin?

Comment: I don't want to use form validation plugin because I want to learn it hard way and improve my regex skills

Comment: Okay, well you hadn't mentioned regex previously and you still haven't posted your code so that we can more easily help you. You obviously don't want a complete solution as you want to learn and for that I congratulate you but without knowing what you've tried it's hard to propose an answer that helps you learn.

Comment: updated the question with my code

Comment: (regex was already one of the tags :))

Comment: So are you trying to check for x integers ("10 150 1 23") or a string of x digits("23423423")?

Comment: Can you please add sample input, that I can better understand what you want to verify?

Comment: @Arda: It's a check for at least 5 **digits** not integers.

Comment: That was a language/translation barriage. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `regex` providing the range of numbers you can afford in your field

like `\d{5,10} // Here 5 -10 is the range of numbers`

```
function testContact(contact){
 contact = contact.replace(/[a-z]*/g,"");
 return (contact == contact.match(/\d{5,10}/))?true:false;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to anchor the regex with `^` and `$`

Comment: And that's only going to check for a single integer with 5-10 digits not x integers.

Comment: something like this? var number = /^(\w\d{5,10})?$/; // But there's an issue, will it also fall true if there are also non-integers?

Comment: @Arda - check function in update.. why are you including `\w`??

Comment: Please check my jsfiddle on the question

Comment: @Arda - You should have specified this clearly in the question, Check my updated function now.

Comment: Sorry for not being totally spesific. Your function works flawlessly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To match a number of integers using a regex you'd need something like:

```
^((\d*)\s*)*$
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd write a small function that will do the job. Note that this function will return false if you have any non-int elements in the `inputText` :-

```
function HasRequiredIntegers(inputText, requiredIntegers) {
    var elems = inputText.split(/\s+/);
    var intCount = 0;
    var nonIntCount = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        if (((parseFloat(elems[i]) == parseInt(elems[i])) && !isNaN(elems[i]))) {
            intCount++;
        }
        else {
            nonIntCount++;
        }
    }

    return (intCount >= requiredIntegers && nonIntCount == 0);
}
```

Comment: I did, sir.  In your example, you are passing an empty string and are requiring it to have 5 integers.  Under these circumstances, false is the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function hasUpTo5(strin){
        if( string.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').length <= 5){
            return true
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    alert( hasUpTo5("fhsfbgurb3utn55nun44") );
```